# reference at overloading operator in c++

Tags: c++, reference, overloading

I am new to c++, and I was recently trying to understand overloading functions. I have questions about references in operator overloading. I get that  CBoys& is reference to class CBoys, but i dont see difference  in following 5 overload of operator =.

```
class CBoys{
//operator=(const CBoys&);
//operator=(const CBoys);
}
// CBoys& operator=(const CBoys&);
// CBoys operator=(const CBoys&);
// CBoys& operator=(const CBoys);
```

Thx for help

Comment: I edited question a bit

Comment: `operator=` must always be a member function, so the last three are invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for starters,

```
operator = (const CBoys&);
```

and

```
operator = (const CBoys);
```

are invalid. The only time when you omit the return type (operators are just like functions) is when you are overloading *conversion* operators. e.g.

```
operator bool();
```

when defined within your type will create a method to implicitly convert your type to bools.

As for the rest, they all differ based on their return types and the parameters they take in. The first one, `CBoys& operator=(const CBoys&);` takes in a reference to a constant CBoys and returns a reference to a CBoys. The second one returns a CBoys by value. The third one, while fine, makes a copy of the CBoys you pass into it (the object on the right hand side.)

Long story short, the constness and reference-ness of the parameters to an operator overload mean the same thing that they do in regular function declarations.

Implementing a copy assignment operator overload is typically pretty straight-forward:

```
class CBoys {
    // stuff
public:
    CBoys& operator = (const CBoys& rhs) {
        CBoys temp(rhs); // make a copy.
        using std::swap;
        swap(*this, temp); // and swap the old *this with the new object.
        return *this; // return the object by-reference.
    }
};
```

This allows us to use the assignment operator in a straight-forward way with no surprises, as it behaves like the assignment operator for built-in types. For more information on copy assignment operators, see here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator

I hope this helps your understanding.